# HTML page - edit option dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dhtml

I've a requirement where I'll show the HTML page(basically a source file of java) to the end user.  I am looking for an option to select few lines like... during onClick it should start selecting the line and upon releasing click it should select the lines I've scrolled and underneath it should show the text area to enter my comments and also it should provide a button to submit comment I entered. Any help in this regard is well appreciated.

Comment: If it's showing the text *as* text, shouldn't the normal click-and-drag text-selection of most GUIs work normally to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah..I'm not just talking about selection. After selection it should dynamically open that text area to enter the comments. This text area should open up only if some one selects the portion of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a **text annotator**.

Something like [this one](http://pkedu.fbt.wur.nl/~koos/jQueryTextAnnotator/) for jQuery (scroll down for the demo).